# How can I open multiple urls to read in c#

Tags: c#

Here's what I got so far:

```
string[] urls = new string[2];
urls[1] = "https://exampletext.com/example1";
urls[2] = "https://exampletext.com/example2";

Console.WriteLine("\nSearching url...\n");
int count=1;
while (count < 3)
{
    var url = urls[count];
    var client = new WebClient();
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string linetext;

            while ((linetext = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(linetext);
            }

        }
    count++;
}
```

How do I make it so that I cycle to those two(or potentially more) urls? I was thinking doing `using (string[] urls = new string[2]){...}` but I'm not sure if that'd work. I'm very new to VS and c#, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: set count = 0; array indexing start with 0

Comment: `foreach(string url in new String[] {'url1', 'url2', 'url3'}) {...}`

Comment: To expand on Zaheer's comment, arrays are 0 based. That means you don't start at 1, you start at 0. So you'd do `urls[0]  = "..."; urls[1] = "...";`. Then in your loop you'd want `while (count < 2)`

Comment: If you don't care about the index, you can use a foreach loop: foreach (string url in urls) { doStuffHere(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array goes from 0 to 1, but you're looping from 1 to 2.  (I'm surprised you're even able to set `urls[2]` to a value without an exception.)

Semantically it would probably make more sense if you just use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parallel foreach which will access all multiple urls

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Use a for loop, or a foreach loop.
- All Indexes start at 0.

code:

```
string[] urls = new string[2];
urls[0] = "https://exampletext.com/example1";
urls[1] = "https://exampletext.com/example2";

Console.WriteLine("\nSearching url...\n");
for(int count = 0; count < urls.Length; count++)
{
    var url = urls[count];
    var client = new WebClient();
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string linetext;

            while ((linetext = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(linetext);
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array in c# start with 0 index, you are initializing it with 1 you missed zero.

alternatively you can try something like:

```
foreach(string url in new String[] {"https://exampletext.com/example1", "https://exampletext.com/example2", "https://exampletext.com/example3"}) 
{
   // read url here
}
```